# Regarding the role of Kolmogorov's theorem in stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

When studying the time series using book of **Time Series: Theory and Methods**, I read the following theorem about distribution function.

[image]

I am not very clear how to understand this theorem, or what does this theorem tell us?

Comment: Why do you "think it should be treated as one of the essential theorems" if you "do not know how to understand its role"? I am unable to understand what it is you are asking.

Comment: @Did, I modified my original question. My understanding is that, the left side is a marginal distribution on n dimensional space, and the right side is a probability distribution on the n-1 dimensional space. I am not very clear what does their equivalence can tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe one can work backwards and assume there exists some process $X$ with distribution functions $(F_t)$, that is, such that for every $t$ in $T$ and every $x=(x_s)_{s\in t}$,
$$
F_t(x)=P(\forall s\in t,X_s\leqslant x_s).
$$
Apply this to $t\cup\{r\}$ and to the vector made of $x=(x_s)_{s\in t}$ and $x_r=z$. In the limit $z\to+\infty$, the RHS involves the event
$$
\bigcup_{z}\{X_r\leqslant z,\forall s\in t,X_s\leqslant x_s\}=\{\forall s\in t,X_s\leqslant x_s\},
$$
thus one must have
$$
\lim_{z\to+\infty}F_{t\cup\{r\}}(x,z)=F_t(x).
$$
Kolmogorov theorem states that this (obviously necessary) condition on the family of distributions $(F_t)$ is also sufficient for such a stochastic process $X$ to exist.

Answer (score 1):

I would be more than happy to be corrected. As far as I am aware, this is also known as Kolomogrov extension theorem. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem
This is perhaps stated better.

This is a consistency theorem for stochastic processes. It effectively says finite dimensional distributions determine what a stochastic process is, as long as it satisfies these consistency criteria.

Comment: Actually uniqueness can be tricky. What Kolmogorov provides is existence.

Comment: @Did thanks for the correction. so where does uniqueness come from?

Comment: @Did also the wiki links seems to suggest the measure is unique, at least if it is a canonical process.

Comment: Try $X_t(\omega)=0$ if $t\ne\omega$ and $X_t(t)=1$ for $t$ in $T=[0,1]$ and $\omega$ in $\Omega=[0,1]$. Then every finite-dimensional distribution of $(X_t)$ makes it undistinguishable from the zero process.